# Redshift Dist key, IDentity column or join column? Cardinality of Column, Used in Join consideration for sort Key

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table that has an Identity column called ID and another column called DateID that references another table.

The date column is used in joins but the ID column has much more cardinality.

Distinct count for ID column : 657167
Distinct count for DateID column: 350

Can anyone please provide any insights as to which column would be a better choice for distribution key?

---

*Also regarding another question:
I have a dilemma in selecting sort and dist keys in my table.
sort Keys
Should I consider cardinality when selecting a sort key?

- A column that would join with other tables would be candidates for a sort key, Is my assumption correct?
- If I use compound sort key and use two columns does the order of columns matter?
- If I define the column DateID as dist key should I put DateID in front of customerId while defining compound sort keys?*

*another question merged to this old question as they are related.*

---

P.S. I read some articles regarding choosing dist key and they say I should be using a column that is used in joining with other tables and has greater cardinality.

`SELECT SP.*,
       CP.*,
       TV.*
FROM
(
    SELECT * --> there are about 20 aggregation statements in the select statement
    FROM FactCustomer f -- contains about 600K records 
        JOIN DimDate d -- contains about 700 records
            ON f.DateID = d.DateID
        JOIN DimTime t -- contains 24 records
            ON f.TimeID = t.HourID
        JOIN DimSalesBranch s -- contains about 64K records
            ON f.BranchID = s.BranchID
    WHERE s.BranchID IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 )
          AND d.DateTimeInfo >= (CASE
                                     WHEN s.OpeningDate > '2018-01-01' THEN
                                         s.OpeningDate
                                     ELSE
                                         '2018-01-01'
                                 END
                                )
          AND d.DateTimeInfo <= '2018-12-31'
          AND StartHour >= 9
          AND starthour > 0
          AND (EndHour <= 22)
) SP
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT * --> there are about 20 aggregation statements in the select statement
        FROM FactCustomer f
            JOIN DimDate d
                ON f.DateID = d.DateID
            JOIN DimTime t
                ON f.TimeID = t.HourID
            JOIN DimSalesBranch s
                ON f.BranchID = s.BranchID
        WHERE s.BranchID IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 )
              AND d.DateTimeInfo >= (CASE
                                         WHEN s.OpeningDate > '2018-01-01' THEN
                                             s.OpeningDate
                                         ELSE
                                             '2018-01-01'
                                     END
                                    )
              AND d.DateTimeInfo <= '2018-09-16'
              AND StartHour >= 9
              AND (EndHour <= 22)
    ) CP
        ON SP.StartDate = CP.StartDate_CP
           AND SP.EndDate = CP.EndDate_CP
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT * --> there are about 6 aggregation statements in the select statement
        FROM FactSalesTargetBranch f
            JOIN DimDate d
                ON f.DateID = d.DateID
            JOIN DimSalesBranch s
                ON f.BranchID = s.BranchID
        WHERE s.BranchID IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 )
              AND d.DateTimeInfo >= (CASE
                                         WHEN s.OpeningDate > '2018-01-01' THEN
                                             s.OpeningDate
                                         ELSE
                                             '2018-01-01'
                                     END
                                    )
              AND d.DateTimeInfo <= '2018-09-16'
    ) TV
        ON SP.StartDate = TV.StartDate_TV
           AND SP.EndDate = TV.EndDate_TV;`

Any insights much appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: what are you joining dateid with? a date table?

Comment: Yes it joins to a date table. I have lots of tables with dateID column that joins with the date table itself as well as with other tables. would you recommend using even distribution by dateID column?

Comment: yes "even" distribution - note that "even" distribution does not require a column

Comment: do you have any large joins between multiple large tables?

Comment: I have data in tables ranging upto 10 million( multiple tables with such amount of data), I am not sure what would consider as a large table, would you please provide your insight? In the example in my post the date table contains about 700 rows and the fact table has about 600K records. Given such records should I even be using the dist keys?.

Comment: the date table can be given "all" dist as per my answer below.. what cols do you join your large tables on?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have used the distribution of all to dimension tables and even to fact tables, this does seem to reduce execution time. 
Would you please provide your insight regarding my question on sort keys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case

1. Use "even" distribution for your main table, this will allow good
   paralellism. (dateid will be a bad candidate)
2. Use "all" distribution for your dateid table (the smaller table that
   you join with)

Generally, "even" distribution is a good choice and will give you the best results unless you need to join large tables together.

see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_choosing_dist_sort.html

Comment: Thanks for your insight Jon. The ID and dateID column is from my fact table. 
- Would you recommend using even distribution to my fact table and then "all" distribution to my date table?
- Also If you wouldn't mind, Would you please let me know what I should consider as a "large table"? How many rows would be a large table?

Comment: large = millions of rows if you are on a 1 node redshift system, yes that is exactly what i am saying in the answer.

Comment: Hey @jon-scott, I am on a 1 cluster 2 nodes redshift system. I tried the dist style to all for date table and dist style even for my fact table. I did not see any changes to the execution period but might be because of query compilation cache(i have turned off result cache for benchmarking). I'll retest and check.

My another query for you if you wouldn't mind, If I have 5 fact tables and I constantly use these tables and join with dimension tables using same join column. Do you recommend using even distribution for all my fact tables as I don't have much data in my system as of now?

Comment: please can you add the sql that you are using to your question? also - how long (in seconds) is the query taking? and finally, what is your needed speed?

Comment: Hey @jon, my actual requirement regarding speed is to **make my 1st execution as fast as possible** with optimizations. The same data in mysql runs in 10 seconds and it used to take same time or more in redshift. My understanding is that redshift queries should be way faster than in mysql. **even the first execution**. My primary goal is to make 1st execution run in *ms*.
I have a set of queries that loads into the dashboard and I want to make them load in the dashboard as fast as possible.

I will try to post my sql here for you to review.
Again Thank you very much for all your inputs :)

Comment: I am not sure how to add code here in comments but here is the link to the code snapshot. Please check. https://imgur.com/a/JfYDlQb

Comment: you need to design your sql on redshift so that it does not change its "template" dynamically each time you run a query. there is no way around that. please can you update your initial question above with samples of first run queries?

Comment: I have updated the main post with link to the query snapshot. Thank you for all your input.

Comment: i am trying to understand why you think the query template has to change each time aka - "i need the first run to run very fast". so pleaser can you indicate what has to change each time? maybe mark it on your query?. also please remove the link to the image an learn how to properly embed code into your question (uts easy)